# In Android, how to launch third party installed applications from my application using localactivitymanager?

Tags: android

I have an application that needs to launch calculator application in resized window on demand and then be able to close the calculator application using close button in my app.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. You cannot embed other applications' code or UI in yours, outside of app widgets.

Also, bear in mind that `LocalActivityManager` is deprecated, and so you should be trying to phase out your use of this class over the next several months.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way to get this done other than LocalActivityManager?

Comment: @Jack: Write a calculator and embed it in your app.

Comment: What about launching any application from android market (Which is already installed on my device or via browser) like games or any news paper app?

Comment: @Jack: You are certainly welcome to call `startActivity()` to launch something, if there is a documented and supported `Intent` for doing so. This would appear to have nothing much to do with your question, though.